# Who are the TWO?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, personal-pronouns

In the context below:

> Any of the varieties of IEEE 802.11 wireless network begins with an
>   access point, or AP, a network node connected directly to a wired
>   local area network or to the Internet. The other wireless nodes,
>   called stations, each have a transmitter/receiver working in a
>   matching bandwidth.
>
> When a notebook, for example, connects to the network, it broadcasts a
>   probe request identifying itself and asking if any other 802.11
>   devices are within range.
>
> If an access point within that range picks up the probe request, the
>   AP broadcasts an acknowledgment, and **the two** go through whatever
>   security or payment arrangements the network has set up. They also
>   establish any settings needed so the notebook can talk with the rest
>   of the network.

Who are **the TWO**?  The AP and the probe request?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"**The two**" here refers to **the notebook** and **the other WiFi (802.11) device** from "if any other 802.11 devices are within range". This means the AP (access point) will acknowledge the connection request between **the notebook** and **the other WiFi devices the notebook is trying to connect to**

Comment: Agree, but it should be pointed out that the fault lies with the original writer, not the reader.  The reference to “the notebook” is too far back in a previous paragraph.  This is akin to a dangling modifier: the reference of “the two” **should** be to the most recent two things (the AP and the probe request), but the author meant the AP and the notebook computer (“client”).